# Follow an object state in Visual Studio debug mode

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Say I have a WinForm, in which I have a `private int selectedObjectsCount`.

Is there a way in debug mode to "follow" this object state through the debug session?

Or, other case, I have a `myFont` instance. I want to see in what moment its property `IsBold` changes (is modified)

I need a trace, because an object became "bad valued" and I don't understand *where* that happens.

Is something similar possible in VS 2010?

Answer (score 1):

In such case I implement `selectedObjectsCount` as property and in setter I do check on value changing:

```
set
{
    if (M_selectedObjectsCount != value)
    {
        selectedObjectsCount = value;//break here
    }
}
```

Comment: and for the second (font) case? that in fact is my actual "problem". Follow an object property's modifications

Comment: No reason to stop debugging in order to add this check - you can instead just add a conditional breakpoint with that condition (right click your breakpoint and choose "Condition").

Comment: @Omer: don't see anybody talking about "stop debugging"... the problem is in property's modification detection and tracing.

Comment: I was just commenting that if the "M_selectedObjectsCount != value" part is not part of the original property, you wouldn't need to add it to the code, you could add it instead as the Breakpoint Condition (without exiting debug/running mode).

Answer (score 1):

Make a breakpoint wherever suitable to see when object changes, right click breakpoint and select "When hit..." here you can print the object content in a debug window -- effectively seeing when the object changes and to what.

At any breakpoint you will have a full trace in the "Call stack" debug window.

The art of debugging is something you should value and learn (it will pay off). See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esta7c62%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for a very simple overview of debugging alternatives in VS.

Comment: I need a trace, because an object became "bad valued" and I don't understand WHERE.

Comment: @seriho: by default, the "When Hit" Tracepoint nessage will trace which method it is printing from.

Comment: @Omer Raviv: So, if I set myPanel.Width in million of places, you suggest me to set million breakpoints, this is your idea?

Comment: I'm not saying it's a good solution, I'm just saying there isn't a better solution in Visual Studio :)

Comment: @Omer Raviv: setting a million of breackpoints is not a solution even... more that than if we take our example, the Width property can be modified by the Framework code as well(say, when Applying a Dock=Fill), so there I can't set breackpoints.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The only way I know of to tackle that is to use .NET Reflector, choose the property setter you're interested in, right click and choose Analyze, and then clicked "Used By", just to see where the values *might* be coming from. Reflector Pro also has an option to debug decompiled code, so you could use that to put a breakpoint in a setter in code you don't own. Conversely, if the setter is in the .NET framework, you can download the .NET framework source code from Microsoft (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) , then put a breakpoint in the setter.

Comment: ... and even then, if the setter is altering some private field, the only way to be sure you're covering all the cases is to do Resharper->Value Origins on that backing field and put breakpoints wherever it is changed (it might be changed directly some other place in the class!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Watch window. If you don't see it in bottom of your VS, you can turn it on by going to Debug->Windows->Watch->Watch 1 (or other Watch windows). This menu item is only available while you are debugging.

You can add objects, their properties and even expressions there, and watch their values while you trace. Items are added by double clicking last row in Watch window and entering your expression in Name column.

E.g. enter *Height* in name while you're debugging inside a form and you'll see it's value.
You can also do things like, *(Height + Width) / 2*.

You cannot however set breakpoint on value change. But while tracing, row who's value is changed will get highlighted. Unfortunately, you have to step through code, you cannot just run it.

Comment: I need a trace, because an object became "bad valued" and I don't understand WHERE.

Comment: I am not novice in VS, so, I know about Watch window, but this window does not help to "trace" object state when the code is running, but when a breackpoint is reached.

Comment: If you know places where variable is changed, you can make VS log changes of object values. To do this set breakpoints in all places where value is changed, right-click breakpoint, click _When hit..._. In popup window, check _Print a message_, and enter message you want printed (you can print value you want there), and check _Continue execution_. That way, each time that line is executed, new value can be printed, but execution won't be stopped. VS doesn't have '_tell me when and where this value changes_' or '_break when it changes_' functionality.

Comment: If you get a "bad valued" pointer, then probably your object was already deallocated.
This usually happens when you have a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

If you have 2 pointers, 'p' and 'q', and both points to the same object 'o'. if you call "delete p; p = NULL", you still have 'q' pointing to an old reference that no longer exists.

A good way to debug or trace where it was deallocated is to set a breakpoint at your object destructor and then analyse its Call Stack.

Answer (score 0):

As other have stated, there are no "Data Breakpoints" in .NET. The best you can do, in case you own the variable you want to track, is to put a breapoint inside the setter, then right click the breakpoint, choose Conditional Breakpoint to check that indeed the value is changing. In case the variable you want to track is a field, you'd have to convert it to a property.

In case you don't own the code of the property, you can use Resharper's Value Origin feature to quickly find all the places where the property is being set by your code, and put breakpoints there: a lot of work but it gets the job done.

Comment: so, for properties like Font.Bold, Panel.Width, button.BackColor there is no solution?..

Answer (score 0):

Are you an ex-Visual Interdev/VB6 user?

I remember that you could set a breakpoint to "break when value changes". Unfortunately that's not possible with subsequent versions.

I think @TheNIK's idea of replacing with a property is probably you're best bet. Or using 'view all references' and then doing a print "When hit" as @TeddHansen says.

Comment: imagine that I have a panel that suddenly, changes its Width. I need to track where this happens.

Comment: @serhio, Override/new the Width property and break on it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this in Visual Studio 2010.  What you need to use is the 'Debug/New Breakpoint/New Data Breakpoint...' menu option.

However, the option is only available for native C++ projects.

For more information, see here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0.aspx

[edit] - For other languages and your specific situation, you could create a new class which inherited from the Font class and override the IsBold property. Put your breakpoint in there and use this new custom class instead of Font. It's a bit long winded, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

Technically there are no "Data breakpoints" in C# since the objects  move in memory during the Garbage collections compact phase.
But often you can do this trick with properties - properties are compiled into setter and getter methods, and you can set breakpoint on them just like any other method.

I have just answered a very similar question here:

[Reasking about hitting breakpoint at property setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438485/reasking-about-hitting-breakpoint-at-property-setter/31861557#31861557)