# How to track which methods called and what values changed in debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I can set some break point or press F11 for seeing what happens in the next step. but I want to just run the app, work with it and at the end see what methods called and which values assigned to a variable. some sort of a list, like a stack.

Is this possible in Visual Studio (2013) debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing that is to use the `Intellitrace` feature of Visual Studio Ultimate (yeah, the really expensive edition :( )

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx

`Intellitrace` allows you to make a recording of your app, and that recording can be opened up as a file in VS which you can step through, just like a video recorder. It's very powerful, and MS knew that, which is why it's only included in the very expensive Ultimate edition.

Answer (score 1):

While debugging, you can see the locals window which shows you the variables currently in scope, and what their values are. As well, the call stack window will show the call stack.

If you want a report afterward, then you'll have to use some kind of profiling tool. [Ants Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have just answered a very similar question here:

[Reasking about hitting breakpoint at property setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438485/reasking-about-hitting-breakpoint-at-property-setter/31861557#31861557)

Again, the idea is to utilize the fact that while it is not easily done for objects fields, the properties are compiled into setter and getter methods, and you can put breakpoints on them!