# Why won't these class properties display in the view, and why can't breakpoints be set on them?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a bizarre problem that I can't figure out. I have a domain object similar to the following, with two custom getter properties that (a) do not return any visible value in the view when called, and (b) will not let me set a breakpoint on them to inspect them during execution.

(Note: There are other similar questions regarding setting breakpoints on auto-property setters -- that is NOT my question. My problem is regarding formally declared `get{}` properties.)

Here's an example of how my domain model looks:

```
public class Program : IProgram
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime StatusDate { get; set; }

    public bool HasCompleted
    {
        get
        {
            return (StatusCode == "A" || StatusCode == "B");
        }
    }

    public string HumanizedStatus
    {
        get
        {
            switch (StatusCode)
            {
                case "0": return "Text for 0"; break;
                case "1": return "Text for 1"; break;
                case "2": return "Text for 2"; break;
                case "3": return "Text for 3"; break;
                case "4": return "Text for 4"; break;
                case "5": return "Text for 5"; break;
                case "A": return "Text for A"; break;
                case "B": return "Text for B"; break;
                case "C": return "Text for C"; break;
                case "D": return "Text for D"; break;
                case "E": return "Text for E"; break;
                case "W": return "Text for W"; break;
                default : return "UNKNOWN"; break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This model is attached to a ViewModel that is rendered as a set of table rows in the view as follows:

```
@foreach (var program in Model.Programs)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@program.Code</td>
        <td>@program.Title</td>
        <td>@program.StatusDate</td>
        <td>@program.HumanizedStatus</td>
        <td>@program.HasCompleted</td>
    </tr>
}
```

In the view I see the displayed text for `@program.Code`, `@program.Title`, and `@program.StatusDate`, but I see **nothing** in the view for `@program.HumanizedStatus` or `@program.HasCompleted`. There are other properties displayed after that in my screen and they show up fine as well.

When I attempt to set a breakpoint on either of those properties (by clicking in the left gutter) I get the red ball as expected, but they are never hit when the view is rendered. I can set other breakpoints just fine, and breakpoints set in methods all execute normally, but here they do not. I can also verify via breakpoint in the controller that the model is properly constructed, but the `HumanizedStatus` property returns `null` at that point and the `HasCompleted` method returns false. So I suspect the debugger is showing default "uninitialized" values for them, but I can't figure out why they aren't called. I even added this to the controller action:

```
       if (programs[0].HasCompleted)
        {
            //nop
        }
```

and set a breakpoint on it to inspect the first Program object in the list, and it also returned false for `HasCompleted` and null for `HumanizedStatus`. I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438485/reasking-about-hitting-breakpoint-at-property-setter) for manually setting the breakpoint and received an error message "IntelliSense could not find the specified location. Do you still want to set the breakpoint?". Even if I select "Yes" it still never fires.

I could change them to methods, but then AutoMapper throws an error, which I could work around by excluding them from the mapping, but that is jumping through hoops I shouldn't have to jump through.

The properties are declared in the interface. I am using VS2010, MVC 3.

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Try to restart visual studio and do a clean up. If necessary remove the bin and obj folder. I think it's more an environnement issue than coding.

Comment: Hi Oualid, thanks for the advice. Unfortunately I just cleaned and rebuilt the solution and it still skips right over those breakpoints, and the properties are returning `false` and `null` as before. Really frustrating......