# How to know WHAT or WHO accesses a variable in VS Debugger for C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging, memory-access

I am debugging an existing C# program. There are of course events and event handlers etc.. 
My problem is I don't know where and when in the program this specific variable named X for the purpose of the question is being updated.

When we worked with emulators and microprocessors, I could see what code accesses a specific address in the memory but I am not sure if I could see the same thing in C# debugger.

Comment: Is the variable a property?

Comment: And if it's a field, you could temporarily change it to a property and put a breakpoint in the getter/setter you make.

Comment: Well and if it's a reference type though, and it gets assigned to another variable, just checking for references to X won't really tell you EVERYWHERE the value might be updated.

Comment: Try a data breakpoint? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Nikki9696 Won't work for managed code

Comment: Yeah, i just saw that, sorry. I was also hoping to find a way to do this for managed code. It would be very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. Right click on the variable and select "Find All References"...
2. Do a global solution search-all for the text "x =" and "x=" to find everywhere something is trying to set it.

Comment: Thanks but there is 100 thousands line of embedded code within code and the name changes etc.. So this wont work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure if you mean "what potential points in my code might be able to reach this variable?", or if you mean, "I have a breakpoint on this variable but have no idea how it got here?".

If it's question #2, I'd suggest looking at the call stack (Debug/Windows). Also, if you have multiple thread or tasks in the mix, make sure to View All Threads (same Debug menu) and View All Tasks.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, my question is question #1

Answer (score 0):

You cant really do this for objects fields, but you can do it for Properties (and you can usually change the code and wrap a field in a property without making changes in other code!).

I have answered a similar questions on how you can set a breakpoing on the generated setter method here, by using Oz Code:

[Reasking about hitting breakpoint at property setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438485/reasking-about-hitting-breakpoint-at-property-setter/31861557#31861557)